# Using MetroFramework in VS2013

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

guys! I want use MetroFramework in my Visual Studio Express 2013.
What did I do:

1. Follow to `Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console`
2. Enter this string to it: `Install-Package Winform.Metroframework.Install`
3. Get "installation finished successfully" message
4. In the file "Form1.cs" I changed `public partial class Form1 : Form` to `public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm`.
   From constructor it looks like correct MetroForm, but when I try to add any control I get this error:

[image: MetroFramework using error]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the working project is in this package.

```
Install-Package MetroFramework
```

I am also using metroframework which is from github.
I also make some changes where I want.
so i'll recommend you to download from [this link](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I try install MetroFramework from package which you send, but get the same error. I think may be this problem related with my OS (Windows 7 x64) ?